# In zf2 how to load more than one action in controller in a page

Tags: layout, frameworks, zend-framework2, action

How to show both of  my **Signin** and **Signup** module in a same page,both work fine seperately in their route

```
www.mydomain.com/Signin

www.mydomain.com/SignUp
```

How it is possible to include/call **signup** action while in **Signin** Action ?

Is there any website in LIVE that had been done in ZF2 ?

Can i get any sample project of Zf2 except ZendSkeltonApplication (It doesn't have two actions in a same page) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try use like this, action in your controller

```
public function loginAction()
{
    $signin = $this->forward()
                    ->dispatch('App\Controller\Signin');        

    $signup = $this->forward()
                    ->dispatch('App\Controller\Signup');

    $page = new ViewModel();

    $page->addChild($signin, 'signinBlock');
    $page->addChild($signup, 'signupBlock');
    return $page;
}
```

in your view

```
<?php echo $this->signinBlock ?>
<?php echo $this->signupBlock ?>
```